# Remove "/ " character from Json String using retrofit Android

Tags: android, json, retrofit, retrofit2

```
/{
    "data": [
        {
            "id": "1",
            "text": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua."
        },
        {
            "id": "2",
            "text": "Felis donec et odio pellentesque diam volutpat commodo sed. Non arcu risus quis varius quam quisque. Nibh nisl condimentum id venenatis a condimentum vitae. Vel pharetra vel turpis nunc eget. "
        },
        {
            "id": "3",
            "text": "Volutpat sed cras ornare arcu dui vivamus arcu felis bibendum. Lobortis mattis aliquam faucibus purus in. Aliquam sem fringilla ut morbi tincidunt augue interdum."
        },
        {
            "id": "4",
            "text": "Elit scelerisque mauris pellentesque pulvinar pellentesque habitant morbi tristique. Bibendum at varius vel pharetra vel turpis nunc. Pellentesque sit amet porttitor eget dolor morbi non."
        },
        {
            "id": "5",
            "text": "Urna condimentum mattis pellentesque id. Ac tincidunt vitae semper quis. Massa tincidunt dui ut ornare lectus sit amet. Netus et malesuada fames ac turpis. Nulla facilisi cras fermentum odio eu feugiat pretium nibh."
        },
        {
            "id": "6",
            "text": "Tincidunt id aliquet risus feugiat in ante. Id donec ultrices tincidunt arcu non sodales neque sodales. Turpis massa tincidunt dui ut ornare lectus sit amet est. At ultrices mi tempus imperdiet nulla malesuada pellentesque elit."
        },
        {
            "id": "7",
            "text": "Fermentum posuere urna nec tincidunt praesent semper feugiat. Nulla facilisi etiam dignissim diam quis enim lobortis scelerisque fermentum. At auctor urna nunc id cursus metus aliquam eleifend mi."
        },
        {
            "id": "8",
            "text": "Quisque sagittis purus sit amet volutpat consequat mauris nunc congue. Malesuada fames ac turpis egestas sed. Volutpat ac tincidunt vitae semper. Aliquam nulla facilisi cras fermentum."
        }
    ]
}
```

What should I do in retrofit to remove / at the beginning of JSON?

I have tried the normal approach of implementing retrofit but I don't know how to manipulate the string in retrofit before getting the respons.

Answer (score 0):

You interface like next:

```
public interface MyRetrofitService {
    @GET("/users/{user}")
    Call<String> listRepos(@Path("user") String params);
}
```

Next you will receive response:

```
final MyRetrofitService service = retrofit.create(MyRetrofitService.class);
        service.listRepos("params", new Callback<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Response response) {
                Timber.d(response.toString());
                // Now cleanup string
                final String correct = response.substring(1);

                // Use serialization to bundle it in Java Object
                final Gson gson = new Gson();
                final YourClass correctResponse = 
                        gson.fromJson(correct, YourClass.class);
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Throwable t) {

            }
        });
```

Comment: OP is using Retrofit2. I'm just curious to know, is it possible to pass `Callback<>` implementation as second argument to `listRepos()`  function here? That too without using Retrofit's `enqueue()` or `execute()` methods?

Comment: @Shashanth I didn't get you. Sorry.

Comment: AFAIK, the syntax followed in your answer is only supported in Retrofit v1 and the OP is using Retrofit v2 (check the tags used in question). The syntax we follow in Retrofit v2 is different than the syntax followed in your answer. In v2 you've to use `Callback<>` as return type for the methods declared in interface. And also you've to use `enqueue()` or `execute()` methods to execute an API request in v2.

Comment: It will not work because the onResponse method will not call and it is going in onFailure only.Thanks anyways.